# Loading images takes very long in C++ using OpenCV on Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, image, opencv, vector

I am currently working on a data-driven learning application in C++. I have a huge amount of data, over 300.000 images needing around 3 GB in total.

Regarding my **working environment**:

- Windows 8.1, 64bit
- Visual Studio 2013
- OpenCV
- OpenMP

My **hardware**:

- i7-3770
- 8GB RAM
- SSD (System and Visual Studio)
- HDD

My **problem in short** is, that loading only the images, so 3 GB, takes over 3 hours, which I would like to improve.

The **implementation** is as follows: At first, I am loading some information regarding the images (not the images themselves) from a file. Internally I am using a standard vector, which holds 300.000 pointers to my class Item. Item holds the information loaded from the file and the image (OpenCV Mat), which is NOT loaded yet. Some independent intermediate steps follow. After that, I am iterating through my vector - parallelized using OpenMP - and load the image for each Item using:

```
imread(PATH_TO_FILE, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
```

**What is really strange** to me is, that increasing the amount of images is not a linear increase for the loading time of the images. Using 22.000 images takes around 22 seconds, using 44.000 images takes 1 minute and 43 seconds, 66.000 images takes around 4 minutes and so on.

I am unsure, if this problem is due to a hardware bottleneck (which I assumed at first) or due to an implementation flaw on my side. I have **already considered** a lot, like:

- halving the image bit depth and thus halving the memory size does not decrease the time taken
- my Virtual Memory for my application is maxed at around 4GB, so there should not be too much swapping involved
- there is no difference in loading the data from my system SSD to loading the data from my HDD
- giving the process a higher priority (I chose the highest, which is realtime) improved the runtime a little, however, the runtimes given above do use this improvement already
- even though I am using OpenMP, RessourceManager states that during loading of my images, my application only uses 15% of my CPU. Using prints, I can tell that there are all 8 workers sharing the loading though.
- shrinked the vector size using vector.shrink_to_fit()

These facts seem to me as there is not a hardware problem, but an implementation flaw going on. Is it inefficient to use a huge vector holding over 300.000 pointers? Or anything regarding OpenCV Mat I have not considered? Any hints on how I can pinpoint the problem further?
I appreciate any suggestions on what is causing this behaviour and how I probably could get around it.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: How I load the images into the vector. Note that i renamed some things so there might be typos.

```
void LoadAllImages()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < data->size(); i++)
    {
        Item* cur_item = data->at(i);
        cur_item->setImage(cur_item->loadImage());
    }
}


Mat Item::loadImage()
{
    return imread(IMAGES_PATH + image_name_, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
}


void Item::setImage(Mat img)
{
    img_ = img;
}
```

**EDIT2**: How I setup the vector without images. Note that I used boosts multithreading for this part. Also note, that this parts execution time increases linear with the data.

```
void foo(vector<Item*>* data, const string file_path, const string file_name)
{
    //open file

    string image_name;
    boost::mutex data_mutex;
    boost::thread_group thread_group;
    while (file >> image_name)
    {
        //reading other data regarding the current image

        thread_group.add_thread(new boost::thread(addDataToVectorThread, data, image_name, other_data_read, &data_mutex));
    }
    thread_group.join_all();
}


void FileHandler::addDataToVectorThread(vector<Item*>* data, string image_name, vector<float> other_data, boost::mutex* data_mutex)
{
    Item* item = new Item(other_data, image_name);
    data_mutex->lock();
    data->push_back(item);
    data_mutex->unlock();
}
```

**EDIT3**: I tried the code provided by SSteve and was able to narrow down my problem. This code generates random images of the same size as mine are, so 96x96 with a color depth of 8bit. Note that I changed his code to only generate grayscale images as my images are. Loading 300.000 images on my laptop took like 10 minutes, which is fine.

I simplified my code as much as possible and removed ALL multi-threading. I have changed my code as such, that the images are directly loaded to the Items, so during vector creation.

Watching the Resource Monitor I noticed that my images are taking a LOT of memory. Loading 10.000 images already takes 1 GB. Using CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE instead of CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED halves the memory consumption. I don’t get it, my images are definitely 96x96x8 bit and it is still way too much.

Using my full code but loading the random images created by the code of SSteve using only one color channel takes 100 MB of memory for 10.000 images and some additional stuff. The images alone should take ~90 MB, so it should be fine. This is only a little fraction compared to my images.

**In short**: My images seem to cause the problem, but I don’t get why.

**How I get to these images**: The images I use for the problematic part of my algorithm are preprocessed by me. This preprocessing step is independent and basically scaling down the images. So the images I got to work do have a size of 240x320 and a 16 bit depth. Then I scaled those images to 96x96 and an 8 bit depth.

Is there any possibility that for some reason the images I scaled down are stored in the correct size and this size is correctly displayed in the image properties by Windows, but the images still include some information which should be “removed”? So that they take up more memory than they should? It does not make any sense to me.

Thanks so far for all the help.

Comment: It could be a hardware problem. Try loading your images with some other API for comparison. Make the test application simple: just load the images, nothing more.

Comment: are your images 3GB on hard or on memory? If they are JPEG on hard they will be loaded in the memory as Bitmap. This means they are much more than 3GB in memory

Comment: I don't know OpenCV, but are we talking about 30,000 compressed images that take up about 3GB on the filesystem?  That is, maybe they are being loaded and uncompressed taking up substantially more space causing memory swapping?

Comment: File I/O isn't very parallellisable. 15% CPU is approximately one thread working, one doing I/O, and the remaining six waiting for the one doing I/O.

Comment: Thank you guys for your fast replies!

Comment: @karlphillip: thats a good point, havent tried that. I am looking into it later.

Comment: @Humam Helfawi: No, my images are 1,29 GB in memory. They are PNG, image size is 96x96, 8 bit depth. Just calculated again, they should need around 2.8 GB in RAM.

Comment: @mark: regarding memory as above. I definitelly saw, that some swapping occured. What I dont get is, that as mentioned, my application needs only around 4GB Virtual Memory (including results) and the TaskManager states that my application uses the expected 3GB for the data as physical memory.

Comment: @molbdnilo: Yes, thats totally possible. However, this does not explain the non-linear increse of loading time using more data.

Comment: I have a small doubt about the way you are loading the images into a vector. could you show us that part? or just make sure that no reallocation is happening (you have reserved the right amount of items before pushing)

Comment: @HumamHelfawi: I have added the code snippet to the question. Thing is however, that the vector does already exist at that time. I really just iterate through the vector of Item pointers and set the loaded image to my Item instance. In a nutshell, the code above is really everything that is going on at that point, there is nothing else. And still it takes multiple hours for 3GB. EDIT: I am using an OpenCV Mat within my Item not a pointer to it. However, I dont think that this is a problem since sizeof(Mat) always gives 96 bytes regardless of the image size. I assume internally it is a pointer.

Comment: Out of curiosity, since your title says Windows 8.1, did you try it on other versions of Windows or on other operating systems? (I doubt it makes a difference, but might as well ask.)

Comment: I did not get the wanted part of your code sorry. I was aiming to see how you push your images into a vector(or any container)

Comment: are you building a 64 bit application? Please add the information of how the vector is/was filled in detail.

Comment: @zenzelezz: Nope, I have however tested it also on my notebook which also runs Windows 8.1. Same problem there (except it takes like almost twice as long, which is no surprise ^^).

Comment: if you instead create an empty `vector<cv::Mat>` and `.push_back(imread(...))` all your images without doing anything else, does it take that long time, too?

Comment: @Humam Helfawi: I added the code above. Note however, that I do not use a vector<Mat> but a vector<Item*>, which holds the Mat and other data. Also, creating the vector for all 300.000 images takes only 5 minutes, the heavy part is the one which ONLY loads the images and sets them to the respecitve instance.

Comment: @Micka: Yes, I am building a 64 bit application. I added the code above. Testing the loading time for a vector<Mat> is a good point, I will try this later.

Comment: the low OpenMP CPU usage looks like either waiting for the vector mutex or waiting for another resource is one bottleneck there (just about the CPU usage). you could try to create a single vector for each thread and concatenate them after all threads have finished. This will copy just pointer values (although quite a lot of them). If CPU usage is low for the whole task, OpenMP imread maybe isn't the best idea after all (not sure).

Comment: @Icarus if imread to a `std::vector<cv::Mat>` is similarly slow, try loading without pushing to a vector (but make sure that the compiler doesn't optimize the call away). Then you can find out the decoding/uncompression time needed without any "huge memory consumption" overhead.

Comment: @Micka: Yes, thats probably true but I think molbdnilo is right, that only one thread is reading from I/O. I can say you, that there is not much difference if OpenMP is "activated" or not. But it definitelly does not cause the huge amount of time, it probably just cant work in parallel here. As mentioned, the vector itself and all its instances are NOT created using OpenMP but using boosts multithreading (I tested both). This part works totally fine. Only the reading of the images and setting them to the instance causes trouble, both if OpenMP is used and if it is not used.

Comment: @Micka: Good idea, I will try that later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think OpenCV is your bottleneck. I did a test on my 2009-vintage 2.8 GHz Core 2 Duo MacBook Pro with 8 GB RAM running OS X 10.11.3. I was able to load 300,000 images in 3.3 minutes. 150,000 images took 1.5 minutes.

Here's the program I used to create the 300,000 images. They take about 8.6 GB of space on my hard drive.

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"

using namespace cv;

class Item;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    Mat image(Size(96,96), CV_8UC3);
    RNG rng;
    char fname[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 300000; i++) {
        rng.fill(image, RNG::UNIFORM, 0, 256);
        sprintf(fname, "img%06d.png", i);
        imwrite(fname, image);
        if (0 == i % 500) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the program I used to create the vector of `Item`s and load the images. I think it's similar enough to the code snippets in your question to duplicate the issue.

```
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED -1

String IMAGES_PATH = "/Users/steve/Development/tests/so35602911/images/";

class Item {
public:
    String image_name;
    Mat img_;
    Mat loadImage();
    void setImage(Mat img);
};

Mat Item::loadImage() {
    return imread(IMAGES_PATH + image_name, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
}

void Item::setImage(Mat img) {
    img_ = img;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int imagesToProcess = 300000;

    vector<Item*> items;
    char filename[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < imagesToProcess; i++) {
        Item *theItem = new Item;
        sprintf(filename, "img%06d.png", i);
        theItem->image_name = filename;
        items.push_back(theItem);
    }

    printf("Set up %lu items.\n", items.size());

    time_t startTime = time(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Item* cur_item = items[i];
        cur_item->setImage(cur_item->loadImage());
    }
    time_t endTime = time(0);

    printf("%lu images. Finished in %.1f minutes.\n", items.size(), (endTime - startTime) / 60.0);

    //Show the last image just to prove they got loaded
    //imshow("last", items[items.size() - 1]->img_);
    //waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

I'd suggest removing the code to parallelize the image loading. As pointed out in the comments, file I/O doesn't parallelize well.

If that doesn't help, you should try to run your program (or get someone to run it for you) on Unix or OS X to see if Windows is the culprit.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your input. I have tested the simplified code you provided. And yes, it pretty much captures the problematic functionality of my full application. The only thing I changed was the color channels - my images are gray scale so I used CV_8UC1 instead. On my laptop, also Windows 8.1, it took about 10 minutes to load the 300.000 images  which is totally fine by me. My application used something around 2.7GB in RAM, from which 2,3GB were present in physical RAM.

Comment: The only two differences to my full application are: Item uses an additional 440 bytes per instance, for all 300.000 this are only 125MB.
My images are in different folders in sets of a few thousand. I don't think that one of these causes the bottleneck though.. :/
I will try to debug it further to finally get to a solution for it. Do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Are you saying it still takes hours on the i7 machine but now only 10 minutes on the laptop?

Comment: No. Your code took 10 minutes on my laptop and I am convinced it is even faster on my tower (cannot test it right now). My code takes definitely on both, my laptop and my tower, multiple hours. I was able to narrow down my problem and have added my new insights to the question as EDIT 3.